# where is the root directory of setResource in chisel3?

Tags: riscv, chisel

I'm trying to use BlackBox inside the rocket-chip source code using chisel3.

Before, I tried it using chisel3 template, and it works well when I put the resource in the src/main/resources/alu/custom_ALU.v (setResource("/alu/custom_ALU.v"))

However, when I tried the same thing inside the rocket-chip repo, it shows me FileNotFoundException

Where is the root directory of setResource in the rocket-chip repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [appears](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/blob/87a5a84130207abee6ed85dcd6d0744ed180f686/src/main/scala/firrtl/transforms/BlackBoxSourceHelper.scala#L142) that setResource is relative to the resource directory as defined by sbt. You are correct the default for this is `src/main/resource` if your code is in `src/main/scala`. The problem here, I believe, is rocket-chip invokes firrtl as a separate process instead of as a single multi-project run, so it's probably looking in firrtl's resource directory `rocket-chip/firrtl/src/main/resources`. This is obviously not very helpful so I think this should be changed. Would you mind filing an issue on the [FIRRTL repo](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/issues/new)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I found that the directory you said is correct. I gonna report it later.